# how to render a single page wordpress template with twig

Tags: php, wordpress, twig, wordpress-theming

I've been trying to render a single page wordpress template with Twig, but so far everything has failed.

```
{% extends 'layouts/base.twig' %}

{% block content %} 
    {% for page in pages() %}{{ set_up_page(page) }}                                
        {% include 'content/content-' ~ page.post_name ~ '.twig' %}
    {% endfor %}
{% endblock %}
```

What one of the templates looks like :

```
<section id="about" {{ wp.post_class }}>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-12 text-center">
                <h2 class="section-heading">{{ wp.the_title }}</h2>
                <h3 class="section-subheading text-muted">{{ wp.get_post_meta(wp.get_the_ID() , 'st_page_subtitle', true)  }}</h3> <!-- To be Changed to subtext for title  -->
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-12">
             {{ wp.the_content }}
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

The corresponding functions :

```
        $wpgetpages = new Twig_SimpleFunction("pages", function() { 

                $currentID = get_the_ID();

                $menu_order = wp_get_nav_menu_items('header');

                $menu_items = array();

                foreach($menu_order as $item) {

                    $menu_items[] = $item->ID;
                }

                $args = array('post_type' => 'page',
                              'status' => 'publish',                                  
                              'exclude'=> $currentID,
                              'orderby' => 'menu_order',                                  
                              'order' => 'ASC'
                           );

                $pages = get_posts($args);

                return $pages;

        });     

        $wpsetpages = new Twig_SimpleFunction("set_up_page", function($arg) {   

                setup_postdata($arg);                       

        });

        self::$twig_environment->addFunction($wpposts);
        self::$twig_environment->addFunction($get_theme_options);
        self::$twig_environment->addFunction($wppostdata);          
        self::$twig_environment->addFunction($wpgetpages);
        self::$twig_environment->addFunction($wpsetpages);
```

This brings out the templates but it sets the page title from the template as the title of the home page[image]

Would really appreciate any help on fixing this.

Comment: It doesn't look like you've shared the template code responsible for outputting the title of the page...

Comment: @rnevius I added one of the templates that is rendered

Comment: Have you tried simply using `wp.title`?

Comment: @Bazinga777 could you provide us with (or emphasize) the snippet that holds the code for setting the title?

Comment: @sitilge The wp.the_title is a proxy for the wordpress the_title method. It's weird that the contents of the pages are being shown properly but not the titles for the same. I am using the following theme framework https://github.com/zach-adams/sprig

Comment: @Bazinga777 any results yet?

Comment: @sitilge I had to give up on the sprig and resort back to core php. Looks like the library sprig isn't suited for single page wordpress sites. The developer hasn't updated or replied to any issues on the project page. Never gonna use that project ever again.

Comment: @Bazinga777 sorry to hear that.

Comment: @Bazinga777 are you running a plugin like https://wordpress.org/plugins/twigpress/ ?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if I got your question right but quoting [a similar issue](https://wordpress.org/support/topic/wrong-title-appearing-on-blog-page-template)

> On my single post page, I was using the_title instead of single_post_title.

So try changing

```
<h2 class="section-heading">{{ wp.the_title }}</h2>
```

to

```
<h2 class="section-heading">{{ wp.single_post_title }}</h2>
```

Also, see related:

- https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/single_post_title - use outside loop
- https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_title  - use inside loop

Answer (score 0):

You question is a little bit unclear. But if your main problem is that all single pages rendered in this single page have the heading "HOME" this should do it.

Try changing this:

```
<h2 class="section-heading">{{ wp.the_title }}</h2>
```

to this:

```
<h2 class="section-heading">{{ wp.get_post_meta(wp.get_the_ID() , 'title', true) }}</h2>
```

If it works for the subheading it should work for the title too.

Comment: That is exactly my problem, but i had already done get_the_ID() for the same and it returns the ID of the current page i.e the home page. That is what got me confused.

Comment: What WP Version are you using ? I'll try to recreate the error in my dev box.

Comment: Im on 4.3.1, Here is the link to the theme itself https://www.dropbox.com/s/6wxxkee7k6v8h40/sprig.zip?dl=0

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to use Twig inside a WordPress theme I would highly recommend installing a plugin called Timber. It takes care of a lot of the complicated WordPress-specific integration for you. They have a starter theme you can check out to get a better idea of how to put your theme together: https://github.com/timber/starter-theme

They also have comprehensive documentation, which you can find here: https://github.com/jarednova/timber/wiki